# Is it necessary to synchronize final members?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a database object used in different threads:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;

public class Database
{
  private final PoolDataSource pool = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

  protected Connection connect ()
  {
    synchronized (pool) { return pool.getConnection(); }
  }

  protected void disconnect (Connection connection)
  {
    synchronized (pool) { connection.close(); }
  }
}
```

Is it necessary to synchronize the access to the `pool` member? Or would it be sufficient to avoid the explicit synchronization?

If the synchronization is necessary the code would be broken, because it would not be necessary to call `disconnect` to close the connection. Some code in the class could call `connection.close()` bypassing the synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization is only unnecessary when the `final` fields are immutable; no need to synchronize `final String`s, for example. When you have a field like this one that doesn't hold an immutable object, you still need synchronization unless the object itself (like your `PoolDataSource`) is thread-safe.

Comment: I have updated the question with the correct imports. It is the Oracle implementation.

Answer (score 5):

In general you shouldn't guard access to the final reference with mutex. Because this kinds of fields has safe publication according [Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf).

In your partial case [PoolDataSourceImpl](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e11990/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSourceImpl.html)(or [PoolXADataSourceImpl](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e11990/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolXADataSourceImpl.html)) able to change own state throw methods `getConnection()` and `connection.close();`. So you should check is your implementation of PoolDataSource is a thread safe. Accordingly 
[Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/apxtips.htm#i1005436) looks like DataSource is a thread safe, but not a Connection.

> The Oracle JDBC drivers provide full support for, and are highly
>   optimized for, applications that use Java multithreading. Controlled
>   serial access to a connection, such as that provided by connection
>   caching, is both necessary and encouraged. However, Oracle strongly
>   discourages sharing a database connection among multiple threads.
>   Avoid allowing multiple threads to access a connection simultaneously.
>   If multiple threads must share a connection, use a disciplined
>   begin-using/end-using protocol.

Comment: Note: You don't need synchronization for `connection.close()` as long as only a single thread calls it once per connection.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I am not sure, what type connection has. If connection put hisself back to the pool and pool is not thread safe we need to synchronise `connetion.close()` method.

Comment: True but pools are only useful if you have a multi-threaded application, so they are thread safe. And that means the connections they return must be thread safe - wrapping the original connection if necessary.

Comment: @AaronDigulla you are right, but when I answered I wasn't sure ConnectionPool is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not necessary. There are a couple of reasons when you must use `synchronized`:

1. A variable is changed thread A and read by thread B.

   This can't happen for `final` variables, so this reason is out.
2. You must make changes to several variables and other threads must either see none or all of them.

   Access to a single field doesn't need `synchronized`
3. You must protect the internal state of a complex object. `Map.put()` is such a case. While `x.put()` is just a single access, the update of the internal state of the map will change several variables, so this you need `synchronized` for this case.

   The question is: Do you need it for `pool.getConnection()` or `connection.close()`?

   The answer to this can be found in the documentation of the library / framework that you use.

Generally speaking, connection pools were created to keep a pool of connections for multi-threaded applications, so they should be safe to call without locking on your part.